# Finding current icon when hovering over unordered list items

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div with a class of side and ul with class of nav with and when hovering hover the class tooltip i display the tool tip text class a sub menu of more li items.  What I am trying to accomplish is when I hover over the span with class header I need to turn just the closet icon class white.  Meaning the icon in that current li.

```
<div class="side">
<ul class="nav">

    <li><--so when hovering over this li
        <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt fa-3x fa-alignment"></i> <-- this icon needs to be turned white
        <div class="tooltip">
            <span class="header">Activity</span>
            <ul class="tooltiptext">
                <li><a href="/ActivityLinks/ActivityEvents">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="/ActivityLinks/ActivityEvents">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="/ActivityLinks/ActivityEvents">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="/ActivityLinks/ActivityEvents">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="/ActivityLinks/ActivityEvents">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="/ActivityLinks/ActivityEvents">Events</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>

        <li>
        <i class="fas fa-file-invoice-dollar fa-3x fa-alignment"></i>
        <div class="tooltip">
            <span class="header">Work</span>
            <ul class="tooltiptext">
                <li><a href="/worklink/ActivityEvents">work links</a></li>
                <li><a href="/worklink/ActivityEvents">work links</a></li>
                <li><a href="/worklink/ActivityEvents">work links</a></li>
                <li><a href="/worklink/ActivityEvents">work links</a></li>
                <li><a href="/worklink/ActivityEvents">work links</a></li>
                <li><a href="/worklink/ActivityEvents">work links</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>


        <li>
        <i class="fas fa-hand-holding-usd fa-3x fa-alignment"></i>
        <div class="tooltip">
            <span class="header">other</span>
            <ul class="tooltiptext">
                <li><a href="/otherLink">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="/otherLink">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="/otherLink">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="/otherLink">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="/otherLink">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="/otherLink">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

So I've tried

```
$('span.header').hover(function () {                                    
        $('.fa-alignment').closest('i').css("color", "white");

    });
```

That turns all icons white.  I've looked at sibling selectors and the first selector but not sure how to achieve this behavior.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused reading your question and the comments in your example html.

> What I am trying to accomplish is when I hover over the span with class header I need to turn just the closet icon class white.

Suggests that you want the icon to change color only when hovering `span.header`. In that case you can try:

```
$("span.header").hover(function() {
  $(this).closest("li").find(".fa-alignment").css("color", "white");
}, function() {
  $(this).closest("li").find(".fa-alignment").css("color", "black");
});
```

> <--so when hovering over this li <-- this icon needs to be turned white

Suggests the icon should change color when hovering the `li` (including its children). In that case try this:

```
$(".nav > li").hover(function() {    
  $(this).find(".fa-alignment").css("color", "white");
}, function() {
  $(this).find(".fa-alignment" ).css("color", "black");
});
```

But this last example could easily be achieved using CSS:

```
.nav > li:hover > .fa-alignment {
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$( "li" ).hover(
 function() {    
$( this ).find("i").css("color", "white");
}, function() {
$( this ).find( "i" ).css("color", "black");
 }
);
```